# Need to create a looping menu shell script, cant figure out how to make it loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

So far I have been able to get my script to run, but have not been able to figure out how to get it to loop. Can anybody help me with this? I'll post what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#descripton

clear
echo "Please select a menu item"
echo
echo "1) list files in current directory"
echo "2) display block device layout of system"
echo "3) display last 10 lines of /var/log/messages"
echo "4) display RAM info"
echo "5) Display CPU info"
echo "6) exit the program"
echo
read CHOICE
case $CHOICE in
        1) ls;;
        2) lsblk;;
        3) sudo tail -10 /var/log/messages;;
        4) free -h;;
        5) mpstat -u;;
        6) exit;;
        *) echo "you have made an invalid selection"
esac
```

I'm honestly just not sure what to do to get it to loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: `while true; do echo hello; sleep 1; done`

Comment: where would I put that? at the top before it starts?

Comment: Online tutorials and `help bash` / `help while` should explain it.

Comment: @SlothJesus : For having the user choose a set of alternatives, `select` woould probably be a better choice than `case`, because it implicitly does error handling for incorrect selection.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your code a little bit. Put the printing of options and selecting of choice in separate functions. Added a loop to check non digits or choices greater than 6. It will continuously ask for choices until it an input from 1-6 is given.

```
#!/bin/bash
#descripton

print_options (){
        echo "Please select a menu item"
        echo
        echo "1) list files in current directory"
        echo "2) display block device layout of system"
        echo "3) display last 10 lines of /var/log/messages"
        echo "4) display RAM info"
        echo "5) Display CPU info"
        echo "6) exit the program"
        echo
}

selection (){
case $CHOICE in
        1) ls;;
        2) lsblk;;
        3) sudo tail -10 /var/log/messages;;
        4) free -h;;
        5) mpstat -u;;
        6) exit;;
        *) echo "you have made an invalid selection"
esac
}

print_options
read CHOICE

while [[ $CHOICE =~ [^0-9] || $CHOICE -gt 6 ]]
do
   echo "Invalid choice"
   print_options
   read CHOICE
   selection
done
```